# Find the coordinates of the vector $\vec x =[5,0]$ relative to the basis $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

Following is a homework question. My answer $[-1,1]$ is wrong even though I already verified $(-1)[-5,-6] + [-10,-6]$ is $[5,0]$. I checked stack exchange and it seems like I have the approach. What am I doing wrong?
[image: Following is a homework question]

Edit: Fixed the typo.

Comment: If you have verified that $\left[ 5 \ 0 \right] = \left( -1 \right) \left[ -5 \ -6 \right] + \left( 
1 \right) \left[ -10 \ -6 \right]$, then the coordinates relative to the basis would be $\left[ -1 \ 1 \right]$ and not $\left[ 1 \ -1 \right]$.

Comment: Isn't that the answer I've used (-1,1).

Comment: Nvm I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My calculations were off. I was calculating the negative of the answer.

To solve the question, all you need to do is create two multipliers $a,b$.
$$
a\cdot[-5,-6] + b\cdot[-10,-6] = [5,0]\\
-5a-10b=5 \\
-6a-6b=0 
$$
which gives 
$$
[a,b]= [1,-1]
$$